# Iterating Array of Arrays of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have an array full of arrays of dictionaries

ex:

```
var array1 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
var array2 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
var array3 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
```

**The keys & values are consistent throughout the arrays

then I have one big array containing those arrays

ex:

```
var bigArray = [array1,array2,array3]
```

How do I iterate through everything with a for in loop so I can read each key/value in every dictionary in every array.

Objective-c I could easily do it, but I just started with swift and I'm getting errors (I'm pretty sure due to casting)

Right now I have something like this

```
for arr in bigArray as NSArray {
     for dict in arr as NSDictionary {
         var coordinates : NSString = dict["coordinate"] as NSString
     }
}
```

This unfortunately is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your 3 "arrays" are actually dictionaries. You are declaring them as a list of key-value pairs. That means your loop would simply look like this:

```
var array1 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
var array2 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
var array3 = ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]

var bigArray = [array1,array2,array3]

for dict in bigArray {
    var coordinates = dict["coordinate"]
}
```

Also, you will notice that I did not do any casting to an NSArray or NSDictionary types. It is better to just stick with Swift native containers so you don't have to be constantly casting types to other types.

If you actually had arrays of dictionaries in a big array, it would look like this:

```
var array1 = [["key1":"value1"],["key2":"value2"]]
var array2 = [["key1":"value1"],["key2":"value2"]]
var array3 = [["key1":"value1"],["key2":"value2"]]

var bigArray = [array1,array2,array3]

for arr in bigArray {
    for dict in arr {
        var coordinates = dict["coordinate"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so it turns out the second example is what I have, the only thing is when you do the second for-in loop it gives the error "Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol SequenceType

Comment: @Phil Then you need to show the real declaration of your data. It sounds like your big array is of type [AnyObject] and it shouldn't be unless you are bridging from Objective-C or you have a mix of types in the array.

Comment: Okay got it working, so the second for loop you do need to cast because you cant iterate an AnyObject ... so it would be for dict in arr as NSArray

Comment: @Phil If anything, you should be casting arr to `[[String:String]]` instead of `NSArray`. Again, stick to Swift types and not Objective-C types whenever possible